# Output Dynamic List in C# ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a program which fetches appointments from Microsoft Exchange for a given calendar and I want to output these in an ASP.net file

The "code behind" I have is:

```
DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Today;
        DateTime EndDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
        CalendarView cv = new CalendarView(StartDate, EndDate);
        String MailboxToAccess = "RES_03037@company.com";
        FolderId CalendarFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, MailboxToAccess);
        FindItemsResults<Appointment> fapts = service.FindAppointments(CalendarFolderId, cv);
        if (fapts.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow row = table2.NewRow();

            foreach (Appointment Appoint in fapts)
            {
                //Output to ASPX file

            }
        }
```

I am fairly new to ASP and C#

Your advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: Use `fapts` and assign it as a datasource of a repeater and bind the required field in your `itemdatabound` event.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - how do you do that?

Comment: Check this link :-http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_repeater.asp